# Do I really need small icons when I've provided an icon for xxxhdpi in android?

Tags: android, android-icons, android-resolution

I'm very confused about various icon sizes required in android. Do I really need to have smaller icons for xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi,mdi if I've provided an icon for xxxhdpi and I want to show same icon for every resolution?

Since we are playing in dp why can't android just downsize them?

**PS**: I tried having only xxxhdpi icons and they looked perfectly fine on smaller screens for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).
Just to summarize:

Using a size qualifier does not imply that the resources are only for screens of that size. If you do not provide alternative resources with qualifiers that better match the current device configuration, the system may use whichever resources are the best match.

Caution: If all your resources use a size qualifier that is larger than the current screen, the system will not use them and your application will crash at runtime (for example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a normal-size screen).

Comment: I've read that link already and I know that size qualifiers for dimensions and layouts(like sw) are required to support different screen sizes. But according to OP why would I need smaller icon sizes for different screen sizes? Android downsizes them perfectly and all my apps are running fine with just single icon instances.